# Unable to download https certificate with bash

Tags: java, android, ssl, gradle

I am using gradle to build an Android project. When I try to run the build task, I get the following exception:

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Digging a little bit into it, I discovered that the problem is that I can't authenticate  the site because I don't have the certificate in my cacerts file.

For some reason, the gradle wrapper can't GET this particular xml file. However, when I run:

```
curl https://jitpack.io/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/core/0.8.5.7/core-0.8.5.7.pom
```

I get a response with the XML content. If I open google chrome, I can also access the content and I can even check out the certificate.

I downloaded the certificate from jitpack.io and added to my cacerts file using this tutorial:

http://nerd-ability.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/tech-how-to-fix-sslpeerunverifiedexcept.html

For some reason, it looks like my JVM is not recognizing it.

For testing purposes, I even used the groovy task described in the tutorial to retrieve the xml, but it didn't work, I get the same error.

Can you help me to debug this?

Thank you.

PS: I checked the expiration date of the certificate it is still valid (I downloaded it today)

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Nope, I am connecting directly.

Answer (score 0):

A little worried your being MITM'd but if you don't care then you could just download using http instead of https

```
$ curl http://jitpack.io/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/core/0.8.5.7/core-0.8.5.7.pom
```